# Open Source remote / distributed / persistent JSON object library for Python serverside and Javascript clientside?

Tags: javascript, python, database, browser, nosql

I'd like to be able to have Javascript code manipulate a persistent JSON object in the browser, and have it synchronise with the server, and other clients in real time.

I'm already using MVC separation.
I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
function sendMessageToUser(username, message){
    messageID = window.model.userMessages[username].messages.length;
    window.model.userMessages[username].messages[messageID] = message;
    window.requestModelSync();
}
```

in this example, window.model is a JSON object that is syncronised periodically or on demand, with errors upon collisions, so 'heavy' client code can handle such an event (it is not caught in the example, but if another user messaged the same user at the same time before syncs occurred, an error might be raised by the sync library).

The view code would be called upon a model change and would re-render the messages for the user - in real time.

---

Are there any libraries that do this already that are somewhat simple, and open-source?

Assuming it's not so secure, I'd like to add cookie based user authentication and key / value validation to it, assuming it doesn't exist already - while still using JSON, with no schema's or models required to start hacking.

I've seen Robert Sayre's sync.js which could be a key building block but I'd like to see something more fully formed, and preferably in use already. I.E: COMET, collision avoidance / resolution strategies, low bandwidth use etc already implemented.

If it doesn't exist I'd be happy to work on such a plugin with people skilled in Python and Javascript.

---

I've seen http://persistencejs.org/plugin/sync - it is not JSON, they end up defining their own model class.

I don't want to use something as complex as Apache Wave's API's either. Simplicity for prototyping is a key goal.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase](https://www.firebase.com)  is a good candidate for solving your problem.

There isn't a native Python library, but there is a Python wrapper around the REST API

See:[Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/integrations.html)

[Firebase home page](https://www.firebase.com)

Comment: Message passing is different from JSON syncing. I dont think it supports that does it? Plus it would be good to use something opensource if not FOSS, especially in a post-PRISM age.